# How to split a date column into two columns

Tags: sql, plsql

Please tell me, how to split a date column into two columns:

```
Column
-------------------
28.10.2022 00:25:13
02.11.2022 10:20:23
08.11.2022 08:25:26
29.11.2022 09:50:21
02.12.2022 01:01:13
27.12.2022 22:30:02
```

Need to do this:

```
Column1             | Column2
--------------------+--------------------
28.10.2022 00:25:13 | 02.11.2022 10:20:23
03.11.2022 10:20:23 | 08.11.2022 08:25:26
09.11.2022 08:25:26 | 29.11.2022 09:50:21
30.11.2022 09:50:21 | 02.12.2022 01:01:13
03.12.2022 01:01:13 | 27.12.2022 22:30:02
```

The `table_date` table stores the `ID` of the operation, the date, and the value "BUCKET" which can change on the date

```
WITH groups as 
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY DATE) AS rn,
        (DATE - (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY DATE))) AS grp,
        DATE,
        d.BUCKET, 
        d.id
    FROM 
        table_date d
    WHERE 
        d.id = '123'
)
SELECT
    MIN(g.DATE) AS DATE_IN,
    MAX(g.DATE) AS DATA_OUT, 
    g.id, 
    g.BUCKET
FROM 
    groups g
GROUP BY 
    g.grp, g.id, g.GROUP_ID, g.BUCKET_ID
ORDER BY 
    MIN(g.DATE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution completely different than yours, I resolved it by using `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign a unique sequential number, then I used `GROUP BY` to organize the rows into groups that are expected to represent successive records based on the `rn` column :

```
with cte as (
  select dt, row_number() over (order by dt) as rn
  from table_date
),
grp1 as (
  select min(dt) Column1, max(dt) Column2 
  from cte
  group by round(rn/2)
  having min(dt) <> max(dt)
),
grp2 as (
  select min(dt) Column1, max(dt) Column2 
  from cte
  group by round(rn/2 -0.1)
  having min(dt) <> max(dt)
)
select *
from (
  select * from grp1
  union all 
  select * from grp2
) s
order by COLUMN1
```

Results :

```
COLUMN1              COLUMN2
28.10.2022 00:25:13  02.11.2022 10:20:23
02.11.2022 10:20:23  08.11.2022 08:25:26
08.11.2022 08:25:26  29.11.2022 09:50:21
29.11.2022 09:50:21  02.12.2022 01:01:13
02.12.2022 01:01:13  27.12.2022 22:30:02
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/B_Gyk9QO)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date column is called DATE, you can achieve this using the LEAD window function in combination with the PARTITION BY clause. Here's an example of how you can modify your query to achieve this:

```
WITH groups AS (
      SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY DATE) AS rn,
        LEAD(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY DATE) AS next_date,
        DATE,
        d.BUCKET, 
        d.id
      FROM table_date d
      WHERE d.id = '123'
    )
      
    SELECT
      g.DATE AS DATE_IN,
      g.next_date AS DATE_OUT, 
      g.id, 
      g.BUCKET
    FROM groups g
    WHERE g.next_date IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY g.DATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

See example. Simplest case. We take to_dt from `lead` row and add 24 hour to from_dt, as shown in your example.

```
select t.*
from(
select id
  ,case when (lag(dt)over(partition by id order by dt)) is null then dt
   else dt+ interval '24' hour
   end as from_dt
  ,(lead(dt)over(partition by id order by dt)) as to_dt
  ,bucket
from table_date
) t
where id='123' and to_dt is not null
```

Or this

```
select t.*
from(
select id
  ,case when lag(dt)over(order by dt) is null then dt
   else dt+ interval '24' hour
   end as from_dt
  ,lead(dt)over(order by dt) as to_dt
  ,bucket
from table_date
where id='123'
) t
where to_dt is not null
```